# Returning null value in JSON Deserialization

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize the json string in C#. Following is jsonstring I used. But after deserialize it is giving null value. So what's going wrong with me?

```
string res = @"{   ""root"":{""EmployeeMaster"":{""EmployeeMasterData"":[{""BasicDetails"":{ ""BasicDetail"":{ ""Action"":""Update"",""EmployeeCode"":""0076"",""L2ManagerCode"":2911}}},{""BasicDetails"":{""BasicDetail"":{ ""Designation"":""Branch Incharge"",""Action"":""Update"",""EmployeeCode"":1786,""SubDepartment"":""Branch Manager"",""Department"":""Operations"",""JOBROLE"":""Branch Manager"",}}},{""DependentDetails"":{""DependentDetail"":{""DateOfBirth"":""1972-07-31"",""DependentName"":""Ramani"",""Action"":""Create"",""EmployeeCode"":2923,""Address"":"""",""RelationshipType"":""Mother"",""Gender"":"""",""IsDependent"":""No""}}},{""ContactDetails"":{""ContactDetail"":[{""AddressLine2"":""Turvekere"",""AddressLine1"":""Hallada Hosahalli"",""Action"":""Update"",""Country"":""India"",""City"":""Tumkur"",""Pincode"":572227},{""AddressLine2"":"""",""AddressLine1"":"""",""Action"":""Update"",""State"":"""",""Country"":"""",""City"":"""",""Pincode"":""""}]}},{""BasicDetails"":{""BasicDetail"":{""Action"":""Create"",""L2ManagerName"":""Ratheesh P R"",""IsDisabled"":""No"",""L1ManagerCode"":2771,""SubDepartment"":""Collection Assistant"",""Gender"":""Male"",""EmploymentType"":""Permanent"",""Department"":""Operations"",""L1ManagerName"":""Arun K K"",""Designation"":""Collection Assistant"",""EmployeeCode"":201021,""L2ManagerCode"":2564,""FirstName"":""Vishnu"",""Title"":""Mr."",""EmploymentStatus"":""Active"",""MiddleName"":"""",""DisabilityType"":"""",""OfficialMailID"":"""",""Nationality"":""IND"",""DateOfRelieving"":"""",""DateOfJoining"":""2022-01-20"",""JOBROLE"":"""",""LastName"":""G"",""BirthDate"":""1995-08-28""}}}]}}}";
```

It's not working, because the primitive object is invalid. can anyone please help me to create the class file. thanks in advance

Comment: to be able to properly answer this you should post the model that you are expecting to deserialize into. This error just means that one of the values did not match the expected type. There are ways to debug this, but providing the model will mean that we can debug for you

Comment: Your C# as-is is invalid and will not compile: the C# verbatim string literal is missing a double-`"` for the `Department` property.

Comment: Why do you have a JSON written in this form: `@"{ ""root"": { ... }` and with mistakes in it? Did you write it by hand? Edited while posting here? Since you cannot use that string in your code, could you post the real thing? Formatted, possibly. You can use on-line tools as [JsonFormatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to format and validate your JSON.

Comment: There is a double quote missing almost halfway through, in fact at the 340th character from the start of your code, however that is likely to be a cut'n'paste artifact because it would not compile or produce the message that you are claiming from the code you have posted.

Comment: Final request, please post the code that you used to try to deserialize this content. When the JSON errors are fixed that is no issue with this basic graph.

Comment: What are you using to parse the JSON? How do you parse it? What do you deserialise that JSON into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, it was tested in visual studio

```
var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json); 

List<EmployeeMasterData> employeeMasterData  = jsonParsed["root"]["EmployeeMaster"]
["EmployeeMasterData"].Select(x => AddItems(x)).ToList();

public static EmployeeMasterData AddItems(JToken jt)
{
    var emd = new EmployeeMasterData();
    foreach (var element in ((JObject)jt).Properties())
    {
        if (element.Name == "BasicDetails")
            emd.BasicDetails = element.Value.ToObject<BasicDetails>();
        if (element.Name == "DependentDetails")
            emd.DependentDetails = element.Value.ToObject<DependentDetails>();
        if (element.Name == "ContactDetails")
            emd.ContactDetails = element.Value.ToObject<ContactDetails>();
    }
    return emd;
}
```

classes

```
public class EmployeeMasterData
{

    public BasicDetails BasicDetails { get; set; }

    public DependentDetails DependentDetails { get; set; }

    public ContactDetails ContactDetails { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeMaster
{
    public List<EmployeeMasterData> EmployeeMasterData { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public EmployeeMaster EmployeeMaster { get; set; }
}
public class BasicDetail
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public int? L2ManagerCode { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public string SubDepartment { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string JOBROLE { get; set; }
    public string L2ManagerName { get; set; }
    public string IsDisabled { get; set; }
    public string L1ManagerCode { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string EmploymentType { get; set; }
    public string L1ManagerName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string EmploymentStatus { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string DisabilityType { get; set; }
    public string OfficialMailID { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public string DateOfRelieving { get; set; }
    public string DateOfJoining { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }
}

public class BasicDetails
{
    public BasicDetail BasicDetail { get; set; }
}

public class DependentDetail
{
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string DependentName { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string RelationshipType { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string IsDependent { get; set; }
}

public class DependentDetails
{
    public DependentDetail DependentDetail { get; set; }
}

public class ContactDetail
{
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public object Pincode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class ContactDetails
{
    public List<ContactDetail> ContactDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would suggest the NewtonSoft JSON library if you are working with JSON. You can serialize and deserialize JSON to class, and class to JSON.

With this library you must not parse JSON by yourself.

[JSON Library](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Answer (score -2):

First of all, there are some errors in the Json format. There is an incorrect use of the icon. Additionally, if you specify string for Json, the `\` add symbol is required for each `"`.

You do not need to write @ in front of the string this time.

like this

```
\"DateOfJoining\":\"2022-01-20\"
```

Comment: "if you specify string for Json, the / symbol is required for each semicolon." - this is incorrect. JSON doesn't require **semicolons** (`;`) to be escaped at all (you're thinking of a _colon_ `:` character), and JSON uses backslashes (not forward-slashes) for escapes.

Comment: yes I made a wrong. I meant the " symbol, not a semicolon. I'm making a correction. @Dai

Comment: Within `@"..."` you can also use two double quotes to "escape" a quote. So `@""foobaar""` is perfectly valid

Comment: I didn't imply that it was invalid :). I also highlighted the error in the JSON string. As additional information, I shared this to make the job easier. @derpirscher

Comment: Your words are *"the \ add symbol is required for each ""*. This is wrong if you use `@"..."` i don't see how using an `\"` is any easier than `""`

Comment: Furthermore what do you mean by *"There is an incorrect use of the icon."*? And finally, your example is just wrong, as it uses `/` instead of `\ `

Comment: only for blocked characters, not all. for exple:  " /  @derpirscher

Comment: "There is an incorrect use of the icon." I mean, the field that was written as Department in the JSON that she set up was wrong. @derpirscher